# Dynamically create a Table from a selector form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a NxN table dynamically using JS and HTML. I am taking the user input from a select form. The issue I'm having is that when I want to change the table to a different size of NxN, it adds on the current table instead of crafting a new one of size NxN.

Here's the function I'm using:

```
var event = document.getElementById("picNum").addEventListner("click", createTable());
//Create an nxn table from the selector form
function createTable(){
    var x = document.getElementById("picNum").value / 2;

    //creates the <tr> element
    for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){ 
        var myRow = document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow(i);

        //creates the <td> element
        for(var j = 0; j < x; j++){
            var myTD = myRow.insertCell(j);
            j.innerHTML= "Row-"+ i + "Column-" + j;


    }


    }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!--This creates the selector for the game parameters -->
    <form id = "myForm">
        Select the number of pictures
        <select name ="picNum" id = "picNum" onChange="createTable()">
            <option value = "blank" id= "blank"></option>
            <option value = "8"> 8 </option>
            <option value = "10"> 10 </option>
            <option value = "12"> 12 </option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to empty the table every time you call createTable, start the function like this:

```
function createTable(){
     var Table = document.getElementById("mytable");
     Table.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Thank you. Would the same logic be applied if I wanted to populate the table with images using this line: Table.innerHTML = "<img src = 'smashbros.jpg />'"

Comment: @griplur, although it might technically work its not proper syntax so it isn't advisable. You should stick to tr and tds etc.. for proper table syntax.